# SwiftUI - Create a list with navigation links with data and views from an array

Tags: swift, for-loop, swiftui

I'm trying to create a list with NavigationLinks, where I can store my views in an array and loop through them with a `for` loop. Unfortunately with what I have until now this just doesn't work.

I get this error all the time: *Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with result builder 'ViewBuilder'*

My code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let list = [DiceView(), DomainResolver()] as [Any]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                for i in list {
                    NavigationLink{
                        i
                    } label: {
                        Label("Test", systemImage: "person").foregroundColor(.primary)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for every constructive answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In swiftUI, inside the struct you cannot use for loop. Instead, you can use ForEach.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let list = [DiceView(), DomainResolver()] as [Any]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(list, id: \.self) { i in
                    NavigationLink{
                        i
                    } label: {
                        Label("Test", systemImage: "person").foregroundColor(.primary)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice, that in Foreach you also use **id: .self**, which means that ForEach makes every object unique.

Comment: I get four Errors:
These two on the line with `ForEach`
Cannot convert value of type '[Any]' to expected argument type 'Binding<C>';
Generic parameter 'C' could not be inferred;
These two on the line with `Navigation Link`:
Generic struct 'NavigationLink' requires that 'Binding<_>' conform to 'View';
Static method 'buildBlock' requires that 'Binding<_>' conform to 'View';